# Регулярное выражение для поиска тега с подклассами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Использую preg_replae для поиска и замены областей html.

Так выглядит регулярка:

```
preg_replace : '/<div class=\"verstka\".*?>(<div.*?>(?1)*?<\/div>|.)*?<\/div>/is' : ''
```

Но не могу найти решение для аналогичных дивов с подклассами, например:

- class="verstka inner"
- class="verstka inner outter"
- class="verstka inner outter js etc"

Т.е дальше может будет любое нагромождение классов, нужна универсальная регулярка, писать реплейс под каждый такой набор не разумно, вариаций очень много.

Comment: господи............. https://habr.com/ru/post/471644/ ....  http://parser.valemak.com/php-library-phpquery  .......https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query  .......... https://github.com/tj/php-selector   и т.д.

Comment: Регулярки плохо подходят для парсинга html: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5909792 :)

Comment: `.*?` - сразу после verstka

Comment: так что выбрать то надо?)))